# Implications of calling yield() twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yield

What are the implications of calling `yield()` twice? For example

```
- if yield :content_header
   yield :content_header
- else
  No Content Header
```

Is this going to eat up little bits of time? I can't seem to get content_for? to work :/

Comment: That's basically not quite how you handle yield.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you'd like a default value for your content if none is supplied?

Ryan Bates does something like this in his code (www.railscasts.com):

```
<title><%= h(yield(:title) || "Untitled") %></title>
```

which yields a given title or "Untitled" if none was provided. Also give some of [these](http://railscasts.com/episodes?search=Layout) a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Calling yield twice results in the block being evaluated in the current scope twice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will run everything in the `content_for` block twice, which doesn't make much sense.

Is there any reason you can't handle the conditional logic inside the `content_for`?:

```
<% content_for :content_header do %>
  <% if some_condition %>
    <%= render_some_important_thing %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render_absence_of_thing %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```